# How can I output string to txt file?

Tags: java, file, output

I am working on a DES encrypter in java, and I have the last function that is supposed to output the encrypted data to an output file, Thats the function:

```
public void OutputWrite (int[][] Result) throws IOException{
  String EncryptedMessage="",out="";
  PrintWriter file = new PrintWriter(new File("EncryptedMessage.txt"));
  for (int i = 0; i <Result.length; i++) { 
        for (int j = 0; j <Result[0].length; j++) {
                out = out + String.valueOf(Result[i][j]);
         }
      int x = Integer.parseInt(out,2);
      char c = (char)x;
      EncryptedMessage = EncryptedMessage + c;
      out = out.replace(out,"");
  }
  file.write(EncryptedMessage);
  file.close();
}
```

For some reason when i print the encrypted data on the console it turns out ok, but when output it in the "EncryptedMessage" file, some characters doesnt show.

I tried coping and pasting the output here, but the same thing happened again the same characters dont show

Comment: please follow the naming convention and have methods and variable names start lowercase. If your array isn't square you want the inner for loop to like like this `for (int j = 0; j <Result[i].length; j++) `

Comment: Maybe the characters are there. they might just be non-printable chars

Comment: @user1111726 i think Colin D is right, check your file with a hex editor or something like that

Comment: @Colin.. They do get printed on the console, isnt there a way to print them to a output file ?

Comment: By `do not show` do you mean they are not shown at all or there is something different shown (like e.g. question marks)? Can you provide an example of such output?

Comment: what kind of charset does your console use and what kind of charset does your file use!? What charactars are missing in the file?